# Format the time portion of a DateTime with leading space for single-digit hours

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I'm working on a project where I need to format a string with a bunch of stuff but the pertinent part is the first part - the time of a tour:

Given

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(myClass.StartDateTime);
```

How do I output it with string.Format to show either 10:00 or < space >3:00?

I know I can use a format string like:

```
string  text = string.Format("{0:hh:mm tt}",_start);
```

but that gives me a leading zero (03:00 PM) that I don't want for single digit hours.

Is there something I can add into the format string to do this or do I have to manually substitute a space for a leading zero? (I suspect this is the case but wanted to ask so I can learn how if there is a format method.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it all with a format string, you can use an **alignment component**.  See [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) on MSDN.

> **Format Item Syntax**
>
> Each format item takes the following form and consists of the
>   following components:
>
> `{index[,alignment][:formatString]}`
>
> ...
>
> **Alignment Component**
>
> The optional alignment component is a signed integer indicating the
>   preferred formatted field width. If the value of alignment is less
>   than the length of the formatted string, alignment is ignored and the
>   length of the formatted string is used as the field width. The
>   formatted data in the field is right-aligned if alignment is positive
>   and left-aligned if alignment is negative. If padding is necessary,
>   white space is used. The comma is required if alignment is specified.

You want to right-align the result in an eight-character field, so you would use an alignment component of positive 8 with a format string with a single `h` as in @David Stratton's answer, like this:

```
string _text = string.Format("{0,8:h:mm tt}", _start);
```

Comment: As David said, a better answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
string  _text = string.Format("{0:h:mm tt}",_start).PadLeft(8, ' ');
```

should do it.

The single "h" in the Time Format String will make it so that the zero doesn't show if it is a single digit hour,l and the [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) function will ensure that it is the proper width.

Comment: You could also use an alignment component in the format string to make `string.Format` do the padding for you: `string _text = string.Format("{0,8:h:mm tt}", _start);`

Comment: @Quartermeister -  That is good!  I didn't know that.  That should be a separate answer, and it's better than mine because it addresses it exactly as the OP asked it.

Answer (score 6):

You can have a conditional check in the `ToString` overload.

```
string _text = _start.ToString((_start.Hour > 9) ? "hh:mm tt" : " h:mm tt");
```

Comment: I think you might need a `% 12` and possibly more logic in here - `_start.Hour` ranges from `0` to `23` but `h` and `hh` range from `1` to `12` twice

Comment: @Rawling - Sorry, I'm not quite understanding. Could you give a time where the above would break OP's requirements? The `> 9` was to detect if there are double digits so I guess you could replace that with `_start.Hour.ToString().Length > 1`.

Comment: Well, if it's 1 PM, `_start.Hour` will be `13` but `hh` will give `01`.